# osgi-blueprint static method calling

Tags: blueprint-osgi

Is there a way I can call static methods from blueprint. As per the aries blueprint documentation I can use static functions to create objects, but I could not find if I could do it for classes which offer static functions to do some functionality.

Thanks
Lalit

Answer (score 1):

Example from [this page](http://www.eclipse.org/gemini/blueprint/documentation/reference/1.0.2.RELEASE/html/blueprint.html):

```
<bean id="current-time" class="java.lang.System" factory-method="currentTimeMillis" scope="prototype"/>
```